# PHP Edit Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Editting a field in a table is becoming a headache for me as I cannot figure out simple solutions. My cause of the problem is not being found by my eyes. The updating of the database function is not working. 
 Here is my PHP for viewproducts.php

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ")
                or die(mysql_error()); ;

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo 'There Arent Any Products';
    } else {

        echo "<table border='1' width=100%><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>";
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $info['description']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>£" .$info['price']." </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<img src='../getImage.php?id=" . $info['serial'] ."'/></td>";

            echo '<td> <a href="edit.php?product_id=' . $info['serial'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here is my edit.php page:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error());  

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "";

        $name = $info['name'];
        $description = $info['description'];
        $price = $info['price'];
        $picture = $info['picture'];
    }
?>

<form action="editsuccess.php" method="post">

Product ID:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="serial" disabled/>

<br/>

Name:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>" name="name"/>

<br/>

Description:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $description;?>" name="description"/>

<br/>

Price:<br/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $price;?>" name="price"/>

<br/>

Picture:<br/>
<? echo'<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $info['serial'] .'"/>'?>

</br>

<input type="submit" value="Update Product"/>

</form>
```

And finally here is my editsuccess.php page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../includes/db.php';  
    $id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $info = "UPDATE products SET name='$name', description ='$description', price ='$price' WHERE serial ='$id'";

    mysql_query($info) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    echo "Database updated.";

?>
```

Any help guys?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing `product_id` to your `editsuccess.php` page. Try changing the first line of your `<form>` declaration in `edit.php` to:

```
<form action="editsuccess.php?product_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks clive, its working now! i got 1 more question. how comes i cannot get image to show up with the following code? i got it to show up before on my other pages but not on this page..... <? echo'<img src="../getImage.php?id=' . $info['serial'] .'"/>'?>

Comment: I think because you're setting `$info` to the result of your `mysql_query`, which won't be an array of records like you're expecting. I would guess you need to use `$_POST['serial']` instead

Comment: no its nothing like that, as iv said i got it to work on another page with the same line of code. do you want me to edit my 1st post and post the code for the page thats working and the page that isnt working?

Comment: You can do but it might be better to post another question, you'll get more people looking at it and a better range of answers :)

Comment: lol cheers...i might just do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="serial" disabled/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="product_id" disabled/>
```

You should also remove the `disabled` attribute from the field because a disabled field won't be sent in the form submission

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your not CONNECTED. I see not connection...